# Solana: Recover source and destination public keys given a TransactionSignature

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, anchor-solana

Is there a JS API to recover fromPubkey and toPubkey, given a transaction signature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a transaction signature, you can fetch the transaction using the JSON RPC API's `getTransaction` endpoint: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettransaction

This endpoint allows you to ask for `jsonParsed` encoding, which will actually decode everything for you.  Note that not all transactions support JSON parsing.

EDIT: The below is only applicable for encoded transactions, and is not required for system instructions that contain a parser already.

Assuming the encoded transaction actually contains a transfer instruction to the system program, there's a `decodeTransfer` helper to do this: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/005592998dd107b3d54d9203babe24da681834f5/web3.js/src/system-program.ts#L266

For other transfers, you'll have to write your own decoder in JS.  The Rust side has all of these defined already for you in the `solana-transaction-status` crate: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/transaction-status/src/parse_instruction.rs

Comment: Thanks Jon! Yes, it is a transfer instruction to the system program. Could you help me with an example of how this must be used? All I have is a string corresponding to a transactionSignature.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, I missed the part asking about the signature -- editing my original answer...

Comment: How to use decodeTransfer